# How to serve files from a Chrome extension under different origin?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, same-origin-policy

I would like to serve files from a Chrome extension under different origin than the Chrome extension itself. Ideally, I would like that origins are multiple and can be configured. The idea is that then I can load them inside an `<iframe>` and they have their own isolated origin from anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `sandbox` (either [as an iframe attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) or [via the "sandbox" key in the manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox)) without the `allow-same-origin` directive. Then the page will have a unique origin (and it won't have access to APIs specific to the extension origin).

Comment: Sorry, if that was unclear from my question (should I update it?), but I want controlled origin. So something multiple `iframe`s extension would add to the page would share. The issue with `sandbox` is that it has unique origin and you cannot make one other `iframe` with the same unique origin.

Comment: @Mitar That's not really supported. What is your use case?

Comment: I would like to make an extension which would allow web apps to store some content into a special client-side only origin, so that they can display it in the `iframe`, but the app itself cannot access the content anymore (because it is from different origin). This is easy to do by using extension's origin. But then all web apps share the same extension's origin. I would like that each app can have their own origin for their set of stored content.

Comment: @Mitar Then you could use sandboxed iframes as I proposed, and inject a script that exposes an API that handles the origin-specific capabilities. Or develop an app and use a [`<webview>`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) (note: this is only supported in apps, not in extensions).